# SQL: Count rows until criteria met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a way using SQL-Server to count the number of rows after the current row that are of a certain type, but only count up until the next row of a certain type, at which point the count would restart.
In the below example I need to count 'Sub-Clase Section' after a 'Sub-Clause' or 'Schedule Section' after a 'Schedule'.

Example data:

```
Type                  Title
--------------------------------------------------
Clause                20
Sub-Clause            20.1 A Sub-Clause
Sub-Clause Section    20.1-1 A Sub-Clause Section
Schedule              Schedule 1 to Blah
Schedule Section      1.0 X
Schedule Section      2.0 X
Schedule              Schedule 2 to Blah
Sub-Clause            20.2 A Sub-Clause
Clause                21
Schedule              Schedule 1 to Clause 21
Schedule Section      1.0 X
Schedule Section      2.0 X
```

The output I require would be something like this:

```
Type                  Title                          Count
---------------------------------------------------------------
Clause                20                             0
Sub-Clause            20.1 A Sub-Clause              1
Schedule              Schedule 1 to Blah             2
Schedule              Schedule 2 to Blah             0
Sub-Clause            20.2 A Sub-Clause              0
Clause                21                             0
Schedule              Schedule 1 to Clause 21        2
```

I have come close to a solution using row_number() to identify each row, and then counting the difference between the current row and the next row with the criteria rows filtered out. 
This is quite a crude method and I am sure there is a better way to achieve this. Plus, my method does not work for the last row as it would return a NULL for the count.
A stripped back version of my code is this:

```
SELECT
    Type
  , Title
  , LEAD(myTable.Row#, 1) OVER(ORDER BY Row#) - Row# -1 AS 'Count'
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Row#
  , Type
  , Title
  FROM Content      
  ORDER BY Row# 
  ) AS myTable
WHERE myTable.Type in ('Clause', 'Sub-Clause', 'Schedule')
```

Any suggestions on a better method that will achieve what I need?

Comment: looks like you don't have any column that can use to determine the sequence or ordering of the rows. `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` is not a full-proof method. it is subject to query engine. If you can change the database schema, add a row no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i make some assumption. There is a ID column that can define the sequence of rows

```
-- Schema
declare @Content table
(
    ID  int identity,
    Type    varchar(20),
    Title   varchar(50)
)

-- Sample Data
insert into @Content
SELECT  'Clause',                '20'                       union all
SELECT  'Sub-Clause',            '20.1 A Sub-Clause'        union all
SELECT  'Sub-Clause Section',    '20.1-1 A Sub-Clause Section'  union all
SELECT  'Schedule',              'Schedule 1 to Blah'       union all
SELECT  'Schedule Section',      '1.0 X'                    union all
SELECT  'Schedule Section',      '2.0 X'                    union all
SELECT  'Schedule',              'Schedule 2 to Blah'       union all
SELECT  'Sub-Clause',            '20.2 A Sub-Clause'        union all
SELECT  'Clause',                '21'                       union all
SELECT  'Schedule',              'Schedule 1 to Clause 21'  union all
SELECT  'Schedule Section',      '1.0 X'                    union all
SELECT  'Schedule Section',      '2.0 X'

-- Query
; with 
cte as
(
    -- grp is to identify group by rows with same Type
    -- first set of `Schedule Section` 
    --     and last set of `Schedule Section` will have diff `grp`
    SELECT  *, grp = ID - row_number() over (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY ID)
    FROM    @Content c
),
type_cnt as
(
    -- count no of rows for each type
    SELECT  ID = min(ID), Type, cnt = count(*)
    FROM    cte c
    WHERE   c.Type not in ('Clause', 'Sub-Clause', 'Schedule')
    GROUP BY Type, grp
)
SELECT  c.ID, c.Type, c.Title, cnt = isnull(n.cnt, 0)
FROM    cte c
        outer apply
        (
            SELECT  TOP 1 x.cnt
            FROM    type_cnt x
            WHERE   x.ID    = c.ID + 1
        ) n
WHERE   c.Type in ('Clause', 'Sub-Clause', 'Schedule')
ORDER BY ID

/*  Result
1   Clause      20          0
2   Sub-Clause  20.1 A Sub-Clause   1
4   Schedule    Schedule 1 to Blah  2
7   Schedule    Schedule 2 to Blah  0
8   Sub-Clause  20.2 A Sub-Clause   0
9   Clause      21          0
10  Schedule    Schedule 1 to Clause 21 2
*/
```

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel, that worked perfectly. I have been able to adapt it to my needs very easily as well. Much appreciated.